# HTML - Moving the text in a cell

Tags: html

I need to create a website using exclusively tables (old fashioned way).
I've started with the layout, and since i can only use tables/html, i've encountered some problems.

```
<body>

<table width="1173" height="703" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr style="text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td width="234" height="234" style="background-color:#1e8bc3; background-image:url(images/exercice1_iconeBatterie.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; display: inline-block;">Expérience</td>
        <td width="234" height="234" background="images/exercice1_img1.jpg"></td>
        <td width="234" height="234" style="background-color:#ff9f00">Biographie</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
        <td width="234" height="234" background="images/exercice1_img2.jpg"></td>
        <td width="234" height="234" style="background-color:#f05a49">Compétence</td>
        <td width="234" height="234" background="images/exercice1_img3.jpg"></td>
        <td width="234" height="234" style="background-color:#f86923">Portfolio</td>
        <td width="234" height="234" background="images/exercice1_img4.jpg"></td>   
    </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:white; text-transform:uppercase">
        <td style="background-color:#f86923">Réseaux sociaux</td>
        <td width="234" height="234" background="images/exercice1_img5.jpg"></td>
        <td width="234" height="234" style="background-color:#35bc7a">Blog</td>
        <td width="234" height="234" background="images/exercice1_img6.jpg"></td>
        <td width="234" height="234" style="background-color:#1e8bc3">Contact</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need my text to be aligned under the image at the center of the cell.
When i try to move something, obviously the whole cell is moving. 
What could the structure be, knowing that i'm wrong in there. 
Thanks

Comment: Heres a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/phc6jctg/

All of them apart from 1 seem to be fine? I'm confused as to what the issue is?

Comment: The issue is that at the center of my cell, i need to have a small icon (something like this: http://imgur.com/a/xZ8bq), then the text aligned under it.

Comment: The whole thing needs to look like this: http://imgur.com/a/obDGr

Comment: Got it. What are you using for the icons?

Comment: Would something like this not work? `<img src="theimageurl.png" width="64" /><br/>Réseaux sociaux` or would that break the only tables idea? The `text-align: center` will also center the image :)

Comment: It works perfectly with the <br> thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our comment discussion:

Try using this in the tds of the title blocks:

`<img src="theimageurl.png" width="64" /><br/>Title`

Hope this helps :)